# Can't create a Hadoop sequence file on a local file system

Tags: java, hadoop

[I found this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256194/how-to-create-hadoop-sequence-file-in-local-file-system-without-hadoop-installat) of how to write to a local file system, but it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\temp\test.seq
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Running this on a Windows 10 box. I even tried using the msys git bash shell thinking maybe that would help the JVM simulate a chmod operation. Didn't change anything. Any suggestions on how to do this on Windows?

Comment: hadoop jars are supposed to be in the classpath of hadoop MR programs with accessible HDFS. how on earth is it possible to run a standalone java program with those jars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a Hadoop program using only jars on Windows requires a few steps beyond just referencing the jars.

Credit to [Professor Lu](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jilu/) at University of Helsinki for posting a [Hadoop on Windows guide](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jilu/paper/hadoop_on_win.pdf) for his students.

Here is a rundown of steps I had to take using Windows 10 and Hadoop 2.7.3:

1. Download and extract Hadoop binaries to somewhere like `C:\hadoop-2.7.3`.
2. Download patch files from https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/archive/master.zip and extract them to your `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` directory.
3. Set a `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable.  For example, `C:\hadoop-2.7.3`.
4. Download the Hadoop source code, copy `hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\io\nativeio\NativeIO.java` to your project, and modify line 609 from

   `return access0(path, desiredAccess.accessRight());`

   to

   `return true;`

Answer (score 4):

I too faced this error and it was resolved after following the steps. (Note : I am using Spark 2.0.2 and Hadoop 2.7)

1. Verify whether you are getting "java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.". You check it by running "spark-shell" command.
2. I got the above mentioned error. It occurred because I didn't add "HADOOP_HOME" in environment var. After adding the "HADOOP_HOME", in my case same as "SPARK_HOME", the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is as follows.

In the Project Structure (Intelij), under SDK's ensure there is no other version of Hadoop referenced. In my case - I was running Spark earlier and it was referring Hadoop JAR's and this was causing access issues. Once I removed them and ran the MR job it ran fine.